# c++ "for" iterator. Expression must have pointer to class type but it has type "object*

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers

The code is intended to sort the `initiative` values of `characterbase` objects. Right now, it only sorts two `characterbase` objects.

The code is overly complicated because it is intended to be able to eventually handle sorting 4 to 5 character objects. Which is why I'm using a `for` for just two objects. Originally, it handled references, but I tried to switch the `vector` to just hold pointers using `ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray`. But the compiler is giving some errors with `iterator->setCharacterTurnOrder` and other iterator attempts to access things.

Specifically, it says of the `iterator->` attempts that:

> Expression must have pointer to class type but it has type CharacterBase *

I am still learning pointers, so I'm sorry if this seems stupid.

```
player_ptr = &PC;
enemy_ptr = &Enemy;

ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.push_back(player_ptr);
ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.push_back(enemy_ptr);

for (auto iterator = ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.begin(); iterator != ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.end(); iterator++) {
    engineFeedback = engineFeedback + "\n Name: " + iterator->getCharacterName() + "   Initiative: " + std::to_string(iterator->getCharacterInitiative()) + " Player Character Flag: " + std::to_string(iterator->getIsPlayerCharacter());
    iterator->setCharacterTurnOrder(iterator - ptrCharacterTurnOrderArray.begin() + 1);
    engineFeedback = engineFeedback + "\nTurn Order: " +  std::to_string(iterator->getCharacterTurnOrder());
}
```

Comment: You're guessing and using iterator in different ways. In your for body you attempt to use all of `iterator.`, `iterator->` and `*iterator->`

Comment: Correct. I was guessing to try and solve the problem which was a bad way to go about it. I'll edit it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] -- a short code snippet that is still complete enough that someone (including yourself) can copy the code from the question, compile it, and see the error. *Hint:* if your code is minimal, then "the iterator-> attempts" should become "the iterator-> attempt" (singular). *The code should be intended to demonstrate the error, not to "sort the initiative values of characterbase objects."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying either the `->` or `*` operator directly on an iterator returns a reference to the thing being referred to.

So, using `iterator->...` works fine to access class members when a vector holds object instances.

But, when a vector holds pointers instead, you have to first dereference an iterator to access the actual pointer before then using the `->` operator to access any class members via that pointer, eg `(*iterator)->...`